# pgfplot: accuracy of tick labels

Tags: pgfplots

the y-axis of my diagram uses small numbers like 0,005. I don't want to use a multiplier like 10^-3 which appears by default. If I remove it with

`scaled x ticks = false,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},`

the tick labels are not accurate enough and show ony 0 or 0,1:

[image]

Code used:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
scaled x ticks = false,
x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
scaled y ticks = false,
scale only axis,
width=6cm,
height=5cm,
xmin=0, xmax=30000,
ymin=-0.001, ymax=0.006,
ymajorgrids,
axis on top]
```

How can i get this right?

Comment: By indenting code with four spaces you get a code block, as I did in my edit. When pasting in code, you can select the entire block and hit Ctrl + K (or click the `{}` button above the text field) to get everything indented. Also, it's always best to provide a complete, compilable, yet minimal example, a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-told-i-have-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Try adding

```
yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                  /pgf/number format/precision=3}
```

as an option to the `axis`.

[image]

Left, with `/pgf/number format/precision=3`, right without. Complete code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
   scaled x ticks = false,
   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
   scaled y ticks = false,
   yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed,
                     /pgf/number format/precision=3},
   scale only axis,
   width=6cm,
   height=5cm,
   ymajorgrids,
   axis on top]
      \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (0.2,0.01)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[%
   scaled x ticks = false,
   x tick label style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
   scaled y ticks = false,
   yticklabel style={/pgf/number format/fixed},
   scale only axis,
   width=6cm,
   height=5cm,
   ymajorgrids,
   axis on top]
     \addplot coordinates {(0,0) (0.2,0.01)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```