# PgfPlots - Problem in axis

Tags: pgfplots

Anyone know how to edit the y tick? I want it in decimal form but the output gives tick in scientific notation. Thanks.
[image]

```
    \documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
    \begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    ymin=0,ymax=0.12,
    xtick={30,50,100,150,200,250,300},
    ytick={0,0.02,0.04,0.06,0.08,0.10,0.12},
    legend pos=north east,
    x tick label style={rotate=90,anchor=east}
    ]
    \addplot[mark=*,mark options={fill=white}] coordinates {(30,0.018)(50,0.015)(100,0.0205)(150,0.0145)(200,0.016)(250,0.017)(300,0.014)};
    \addlegendentry{a}
    \addplot[dashed,mark=square*,mark options={solid,fill=white}] coordinates {(30,0.0165)(50,0.031)(100,0.0305)(150,0.0315)(200,0.0365)(250,0.0425)(300,0.043)};
    \addlegendentry{b}
    \addplot[dashdotted,mark=triangle*,mark options={solid,fill=white}] coordinates {(30,0.025)(50,0.025)(100,0.025)(150,0.025)(200,0.025)(250,0.025)(300,0.025)};
    \addlegendentry{c}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: This should help: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/35910/586